# Convert Rows into List of values under a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to get the desired output using pandas:
Convert rows into a list column

**Input format:**

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1    a    r1   2019-10-10
1    a    r2   2019-10-11
1    a    r3   2019-10-12
2    b    r4   2019-10-08
2    b    r5   2019-10-09
```

**Desired Output:**

```
col1 col2 col4         new_column
1    a    2019-10-10   []
1    a    2019-10-11   [r1]
1    a    2019-10-12   [r1,r2]
2    b    2019-10-08   []
2    b    2019-10-09   [r4]
```

Comment: What is the criteria?

Comment: what is ur rule?

Comment: Convert rows into list for col1 and col2 combination for dates less than current date(date present in col4) and assign it to a new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that should do the job! (That suppose that your date column is of type datetime and not string):

```
dictionary = df.groupby(by=['col1','col2']).apply(lambda df2: df2[['col3', 'col4']].to_dict('index')).to_dict()   

def my_func(col1_value, col2_value, my_date, my_dictionary):
    df_bis = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dictionary[(col1_value, col2_value)], orient='index')   
    return df_bis[df_bis['col4'] < my_date].col3.to_list()

df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda row: my_func(row.col1, row.col2, row.col4, dictionary), 
                         axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Hugues GALLIER, you did a nice trick of copying the dataframe into dictionary, and then recreate it for relevant key (col1, col2 combination) with a new dataframe that is then filtered by condition.

@Sunny Kumar, I thank you for this question as I learned that saving list objects inside dataframe is loosing the power of vectorized work behind the scene. so it is most of the times better to save as a string that when used can be interpret into numpy array.

My solution does the same but with a copy of the dataframe (instead of dictionary copy), I think it is simpler:

```
df_temp = df.copy()

def prep_list(col1,col2,col4,df): 
    return df[(df.col1==col1) & (df.col2==col2) & (df.col4 < col4)].col3.to_list()

df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: prep_list(row.col1,row.col2,row.col4,df_temp), axis=1)
```